# How can I get my footnotes placed similarly in the columns of my document

Tags: footnotes

I just noticed that footnotes on the first and last page of a document get placed differently as demonstrated in this MWE.  In this particular example, the problem shows up in a two-column document where the second column is seen by LaTeX to act in the role
of the last page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape,
            twocolumn,
            margin=0.5in,
           ]{geometry}
\setlength{\columnsep}{3em}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

This is a short section\footnote{Hello}

\pagebreak
\setcounter{footnote}{0}

This is a short section\footnote{Hello}

\end{document}
```

For the purposes of my document, the left and right columns should be identically typeset.  So, I'm not happy that the footnotes get placed differently.  What I would prefer is that both footnotes get placed as the first footnote in the left hand column.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Interesting.... could you write that up as a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\pagebreak` command tells LaTeX to break the current page *at the point of the command*. With the optional argument, a number, you can convert the `\pagebreak` command from a demand to a request.  (For details refer  [to this answer by egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83493/11232)). If you don't specify the options, then number 4 is assumed and a page break is inserted immediately.

Coming to your mwe, the `\pagebreak` is called with only one line of text without any optional arguments. Hence, you have insisted (demanded) for a page break *immediately* whereas the second page/column gets shipped out naturally. If you want second column to be identical to first column, put a `\pagebreak` after the second column also.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape,
            twocolumn,
            margin=0.5in,
           ]{geometry}
\setlength{\columnsep}{3em}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

This is a short section\footnote{Hello}

\pagebreak
\setcounter{footnote}{0}

This is a short section\footnote{Hello}
\pagebreak %% put here
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may play with the optional arguments (`\pagebreak[1]`, number from 0-4).

However using `\newpage` or `\clearpage` will give you different results as in these cases, the page is broken at the end.

May be useful:

1. [pagebreak-vs-newpage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/740/11232)
2. [when-do-i-need-invoke-clearpage-manually](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45609/11232)