# Disable hyphenation in footnotes

Tags: footnotes, koma-script, hyphenation

I want to disable hyphenation in footnotes, because I have special codes for a special program and the readers should copy this code into his program and therefore its not good, that there is a hyphen ("-") inside the code. See my example in the third line.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman, frenchb]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{StandardLayout=true}
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\deffootnote{1em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark\ }}

\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}


\begin{document}
This is a test\footnote{\#vfini :[cat="Snt" \& type="VFin"] \& \#vfini >L \#v :[ ] \& \#before\_v :[ ] .* \#v \& \#cat3 :[cat!=/(Rfc|Apst|Ng)/] >* \#before\_v \& \#cat3 >@l \#cat3\_init :[ ] \& \#before\_cat3\_init :[ ] . \#cat3\_init \& \#cat2 :[cat ="Circ"] >* \#before\_cat3\_init \& \#cat2 >@l \#cat2\_init :[ ] \& \#before\_cat2\_init :[ ] . \#cat2\_init \& \#cat1 :[cat!=/(RelNC|Apst|Ng|Circ)/] >* \#before\_cat2\_init \& \#vfini > \#cat1 \& \#vfini > \#cat2 \& \#vfini > \#cat3 \& \#cat1 >@l \#cat1\_init :[ ] \& \#vfini >@l \#cat1\_init}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could just use `\raggedright`. As in, `\footnote{\raggedright ...}`. Since this is code though, I would use some fixed-width font as well.

Comment: Use `\def\nohyph{\hyphenpenalty=10000\relax\exhyphenpenalty=10000\relax}
\addtokomafont{footnote}{\nohyph}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To disable hyphens you can use `\raggedright`, `\raggedleft` or `\centering`. However you will loose your justification. To get a hyphenless justification you can change the relevant penalties `\hyphenpenalty` and `\exhyphenpenalty`. An explanation of defined penalties can be found: [What are penalties and which ones are defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51263/what-are-penalties-and-which-ones-are-defined)

To simplify the call you can define the following macro:

```
\newcommand\nohyph{\hyphenpenalty=10000\relax\exhyphenpenalty=10000\relax}
```

This macro can be used everywhere. To set the behaviour local you can call:

```
\footnote{\nohyph <here your text>}
```

KOMA allows a global modification of the font inside footnotes. You can simply add the defined macro to the definition by:

```
\addtokomafont{footnote}{\nohyph}
```

to set the macro `\nohyph` global.

related to your example I got the following output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot to Marco! You helped me very much. Nice evening.

Comment: Side note: With the package `ragged2e` and the according commands hyphenation will be re-activated.

Answer (score 2):

This looks more like verbatim code than text. I’d use the `\url` macro from the `url` package with the `obeyspaces` option here.
Advantage: You don’t need to escape `&`, `#` or `_`.

Maybe a [`attachfile`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/attachfile) solution would be better to provide readers with code?

### Code (`url`)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\deffootnote{1em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark\ }}
\urlstyle{same}% comment out to get tt font.
\begin{document}
This is a test\footnote{%
\url{#vfini :[cat="Snt" & type="VFin"] & #vfini >L #v :[ ] & #before_v :[ ] .* #v & #cat3 :[cat!=/(Rfc|Apst|Ng)/] >* #before_v & #cat3 >@l #cat3_init :[ ] & #before_cat3_init :[ ] . #cat3_init & #cat2 :[cat ="Circ"] >* #before_cat3_init & #cat2 >@l #cat2_init :[ ] & #before_cat2_init :[ ] . #cat2_init & #cat1 :[cat!=/(RelNC|Apst|Ng|Circ)/] >* #before_cat2_init & #vfini > #cat1 & #vfini > #cat2 & #vfini > #cat3 & #cat1 >@l #cat1_init :[ ] & #vfini >@l #cat1_init}}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

### Code (`attachfile`)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl} 
\begin{filecontents}{code1.txt}
#vfini :[cat="Snt" & type="VFin"] & #vfini >L #v :[ ] & #before_v :[ ] .* #v & #cat3 :[cat!=/(Rfc|Apst|Ng)/] >* #before_v & #cat3 >@l #cat3_init :[ ] & #before_cat3_init :[ ] . #cat3_init & #cat2 :[cat ="Circ"] >* #before_cat3_init & #cat2 >@l #cat2_init :[ ] & #before_cat2_init :[ ] . #cat2_init & #cat1 :[cat!=/(RelNC|Apst|Ng|Circ)/] >* #before_cat2_init & #vfini > #cat1 & #vfini > #cat2 & #vfini > #cat3 & #cat1 >@l #cat1_init :[ ] & #vfini >@l #cat1_init
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{attachfile}
\attachfilesetup{color=.5 0 .5}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\deffootnote{1em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark\ }}
\begin{document}
This is a test\footnote{See \textattachfile{code1.txt}{code sampe 1}.}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]