# List of TeX internal parameters?

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

I have come across quite a number of TeX internal parameters, like `\clubpenalty`, `\widowpenalty`, `\abovedisplayshortskip` and so on. Could you provide me with a complete list of them, what they are for and their default values?

**Edit:**
As David Carlisle suggested, for penalties I find everything at [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51263/what-are-penalties-and-which-ones-are-defined/51264#51264). As for the others, many defaults are missing from both given references. I will make a list below of those explained in [the tug list](http://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html). If you feel I'm missing any parameter, please let me know. The question therefore becomes: what are the defaults of the following parameters?

- `\abovedisplayshortskip`, the non-`short` equivalent, and the `below` equivalents of both;
- `\badness`; is this set to a starting value or is this set the first time with the first box?
- `\baselineskip`, `\prevdepth` (is this set to a starting value or not?), `\lineskiplimit`, `\lineskip`;
- `\boxmaxdepth` and `\maxdepth`, here together since they are often the same value; in fact, in the tug list it is said, under `\pagedepth`, that `\maxdepth` `in plain is 4pt`;
- `\leaders`, `\cleaders` and `\xleaders`;
- What is the starting value of `\deadcycles`? Is it 0?
- `\defaulthyphenchar` is a hyphen (-) by default, right?
- `\defaultskewchar`; what is the `\skewchar`?
- `\delimiterfactor` and `\delimitershortfall`;
- `\displayindent`;
- `\displaywidth`; this is normally `\hsize`, but what is `\hsize` by default?
- `\emergencystretch`, `\pretolerance` and `\tolerance`;
- `\endlinechar`;
- `\errorcontextlines`;
- `\escapechar`;
- `\hangafter`, `\hangindent`;
- `\hbadness`, `\hfuzz`;
- `\holdinginserts`;
- `\inputlineno` starts as 0, I should think;
- Same goes for `\insertpenalties`;
- What is the default (starting value) of `\interlinepenalty`?
- `\lefthyphenmin`;
- `\mag`;
- `\mathsurround`;
- `\maxdeadcycles`;
- `\medmuskip`, `\thinmuskip` and `\thickmuskip`;
- `\nonscript`;
- `\outputpenalty` seems to be missing in the penalty link;
- `\overfullrule`;
- I'd guess `\pagedepth` starts out as 0pt;
- Same goes for `\pagefilstretch`, `\pagefillstretch` and `\pagefilllstretch`;
- Same goes for `\pageshrink` and `\pagestretch`, and `\pagegoal` is completely dealt with on the tug list;
- Same as `\pageshrink` goes for `\pagetotal`;
- `\parfillskip` and `\parskip`;
- `\parindent`;
- `\pausing`;
- What is the starting value of `\predisplaysize`?
- Same question about `\pretolerance`, `\tolerance` and `\prevdepth`;
- And about `\prevgraph`;
- What is the default for `\righthyphenmin`?
- And for `\rightskip` and `\leftskip`?
- And for `\scriptspace`?
- What are `\spacefactor`, `\spaceskip` and `\xspaceskip`, and their default values?
- What are `\splittopmark`, `\topmark` and `\splitfirstmark`'s defaults?
- What are `\splitmaxdepth` and `\splittopskip`?
- What's the default for `\tabskip`?
- For completeness, I list `\time`, though this requires no explanation;
- Default for `\topskip`?
- And `\tracingcommands` and `\tracinglostcommands` and mates (-macros, -online, -output, -pages, -paragraphs, -restores, -stats)?
- And for `\vbadness`, `\vfuzz` and `\voffset` and `\vsize`?

If you feel this is still too broad, answer only about the `dimen` parameters, and notify me. I'll ask separate questions for the rest.

Comment: `texdoc texbytopic`?

Comment: The TeXbook is the best reference but there's a list of primitives at http://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html

Comment: This occupies a large part of the TeXbook; an answer would require much more than the allotted space. And several hours' work.

Comment: Most of the ones you mention are penalties, for which a full list is here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51263/what-are-penalties-and-which-ones-are-defined/51264#51264

Comment: Only @egreg could say that it would take mere hours to properly document all of TeX's internal parameters...

Comment: Everyone please see the edit.

Comment: @MickG Well, I reviewed the question and I voted to leave it closed. I'll try to explain why. It still is too broad, and it doesn't make any sense to explain here how all the internals work. There are books that aim at doing this, but they are couple hundred pages long, and not couple paragraphs. Three good things were already suggested: Read _TeX by Topic_, read _The TeXbook_ or open the primitives reference at tug.org. Since basically only such links can stand as answers, the question doesn't fit in the Q&A format of StackExchange.

Comment: I also reviewed and agree with @tohecz. If you do not have access to a print copy of _The TeXbook_ you can always review its [source](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbook).

Comment: @tohecz I don't want to know how they work. I want to k.ow their starting values only, except in very few cases. And if _that_ is still too broad, we make this question only about `\dimen` params and leave the rest to separate questions. Is telling me what the defaults for the params of that class are and what a few of them are for still too broad?

Comment: And I plan to read TeX by topic - I've already opened it and am waiting for spare time to read it, which in the régime of a 6-course Uni semester surely _doesn't_ about :).

Comment: If I managed to list those params, a "table" with their defaults should fit in an answer, right? Then a few paragraphs (2 at most, I should think) are enough to explain the functioning of the 8 parameters I asked the functioning of, and we're done. What's so terribly long about _that_?

Comment: @MickG "default" in which context? many classes re-define a good portion of them. And btw, you can get the value of any of them using `\the\whateverparameterdimenandsuchhere`.

Comment: Let's say we gloss "default" with "starting values in plain, plus notes as to redefinitions in LaTeX or classes, without new values". What about that @tohecz?

Comment: That would mean the core of the "defaults" part would be a copy-pasted chunk of `plain.tex`, about a hundred lines, plus the redefinition notes. Also, I see some values are in commented lines, so an explanation would be required as to the reason for commenting those lines out.

Comment: Several of those parameters don't have an “initial” value (`\prevdepth`, `\badness`, `\holdinginserts` and `\...mark` are just a few instances) because they frequently change their value at runtime. Others are expected to be set by a format (in LaTeX it would be a class), among them all the `\...skip`. Others have quite predictable defaults (`\escapechar` and `\defaulthyphenchar` among them). Some are quite arcane (`\pausing` and `\uchyph`).

Comment: @MickG See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38674/the-the-command/38680#38680 for how to access the parameters' value.

Comment: @egreg I guess your next-to-last comment, with complete lists of the various categories you mentioned, would do fine as an answer :). Anyway, if this question gets closed, will it end up deleted eventually?

Comment: My comment was just to show a few problems related to answering the question. Knowing that some parameters have default values and others don't is not very useful, is it?

Comment: Well @egreg, it tells me the list of defaults is cut down, and would tell me where to look for the initialization of other parameters (those set by a format - `report` in my case). For the rest, there are default values. Many parameters have an explanation of how they are _changed_ on the tug list, and if one adds they have _no_ defaults, I'm satisfied. If I ask "What is the default for `\x`?", the answer may well be "`\x` has _no_ default", couldn't it :)?