# What are the default values in LaTeX commands or variables

Tags: tex-core, latex-base

How can I know what is the default value for line spacing in LaTeX (for example what is the default value of `\baselinestretch` command before `renewcommand`ing it?) and how I can print this value in the PDF file?

I used `\the\textheight‎‎` to show the default value of text height in the output file.

I just tested these two commands in this simple example (in a `report` class and the font size is default):

```
\documentclass{‎‏‎report‎}‎‎‎

\begin{document}
\the\textheight‎‎
\end{document}
```

and I get `550.0pt` in output.

Is there something like this to know and print all default values of all pre-defined variables in a LaTeX output? (in a `report` class with a default font size for instance)

Comment: Since some of the commands using registers internally, the representation for printing/showing them differs. As far as I know there is no single command from Tex-core (or LaTeX - core) that shows all of them (that would be  quite a lot) in a row. You should use the `\let` - approach in order to store the old definition in order to be able to restore it later on

Comment: The `\baselinestretch` macro expands to `1` for example (by default from LaTeX core). (Looking into `latex.ltx` provides some clue).  Classes and packages might change this value, of course

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38674/the-the-command

Comment: Please consider, that packages and classes add new 'variables' that influence layout/font settings etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

LaTeX allocates

- 56 `\count` registers
- 92 `\dimen` registers
- 31 `\skip` registers
- 16 `\box` registers
- 4 `\toks` registers

Running a document with the `report` class allocates another

- 9 `\count` registers
- 1 `\dimen` register
- 2 `\skip` registers

Several of these parameters are for internal usage. If we exclude parameters with `@` in their name, we get

#### `\count` registers

```
\interfootnotelinepenalty
\interdisplaylinepenalty
```

#### `\dimen` registers

```
\maxdimen
\normallineskiplimit
\jot
\leftmargin
\rightmargin
\listparindent
\itemindent
\labelwidth
\labelsep
\linewidth
\leftmargini
\leftmarginii
\leftmarginiii
\leftmarginiv
\leftmarginv
\leftmarginvi
\fboxrule
\fboxsep
\tabbingsep
\arraycolsep
\tabcolsep
\arrayrulewidth
\doublerulesep
\unitlength
\footnotesep
\topmargin
\oddsidemargin
\evensidemargin
\headheight
\headsep
\footskip
\textheight
\textwidth
\columnwidth
\columnsep
\columnseprule
\marginparwidth
\marginparsep
\marginparpush
\paperheight
\paperwidth
```

#### `\skip` registers

```
\hideskip
\normalbaselineskip
\normallineskip
\smallskipamount
\medskipamount
\bigskipamount
\fill
\topsep
\partopsep
\itemsep
\parsep
\floatsep
\textfloatsep
\intextsep
\dblfloatsep
\dbltextfloatsep
```

The `report` class adds

- `\bibindent` (a `\dimen`)
- `\abovecaptionskip` (a `\skip`)
- `\belowcaptionskip` (a `\skip`)

Packages will add many more.

There are also all the internal parameters of TeX that will have a default value (see [List of TeX internal parameters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203638/list-of-tex-internal-parameters) for a partial list, but you should consult the big manuals, either the TeXbook or TeX by topic).

All these (with the exception of box registers) can be looked at with `\the`.

There are also “pseudovariables”, that is, parameterless macros which hold a value. Among them

```
\baselinestretch
\arraystretch
```

and some more. These can be looked at with `\meaning`.

Comment: Wow, thanks! It's a very nice answer, and I solved my problem with the help of your answer. I used `\the\baselineskip‎` to show this `\skip` register in the output and (for my simple example in the question) I get `12.0pt`. (In the case of my simple example, that was exactly what I wanted to know about `\baselinestretch` pseudovariable!)