# Default values of nested lists

Tags: lists

What registers store the default values for lenghts and glues of the  Latex nested lists?

Or how to calculate them? I have checked that they depend of the fontsize value.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\registers{\the\leftmargin\\ \the\labelwidth[![is][1]][1]\\ \the\topsep}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \registers
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item \registers
         \begin{enumerate}
         \item \registers
                \begin{enumerate}
            \item \registers
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As found on this site somewhere--

From latex2e.pdf: "The `\leftmargini` through `\leftmarginvi` parameters define the distance between the left margin of the enclosing environment and the left margin of the list. By convention, `\leftmargin` is set to the appropriate `\leftmarginN` when a new level of nesting is entered. The defaults vary from ‘.5em’ (highest levels of nesting) to ‘2.5em’ (fist level), and are a bit reduced in two-column mode."

Also see texlive installation, in 
`texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls`, 
lines 337 to 352:

```
\if@twocolumn   \setlength\leftmargini  {2em} 
\else   
\setlength\leftmargini  {2.5em} 
\fi 
\leftmargin  \leftmargini 
\setlength\leftmarginii  {2.2em} 
\setlength\leftmarginiii {1.87em} 
\setlength\leftmarginiv  {1.7em} 
\if@twocolumn   
\setlength\leftmarginv  {.5em}   
\setlength\leftmarginvi {.5em} 
\else   
\setlength\leftmarginv  {1em}   
\setlength\leftmarginvi {1em} 
\fi
```

But better to look in 
texmf-dist/source/latex/base/classes.dtx

Also see
--https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366237/197451