# \clubpenalty and \widowpenalty seem to have no impact

Tags: koma-script, windows

I have a KomaScript Project and i have set the following parameters as it is suggested everywhere around the web:

```
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000
\displaywidowpenalty=10000
\raggedbottom  % this was my last try, it also doesn't seem to have an effect
```

Howvever, there are way to may widows in my document, I believe, the commands do not have any effect at all.

**Example 1**
[image]

**Example 2**
[image]

Are there any pitfalls which may cause these commands to not work properly? The documentclass is `scrreprt` with `twoside` option disabled.

Comment: A one line paragraph is not a widow, as far as TeX is concerned. Without an example, it's impossible to say more.

Comment: i have added 2 images for you to see some examples. i hope that helps

Comment: both those images show two lines being taken over a page not 1 so the penalties have had an effect (or were not needed)

Comment: i thought those commands would prevent exactly this behaviour?

Comment: @nozzleman they are a penalty against a _single_ line being affected by a page break, two lines are considered OK (etex has an extension that allows you to specify penalties for multiple lines into the paragraph)

Comment: alright, thank you very much for that explanation! In this case, my question is nonsense :/

Comment: well you could rephrase it to ask how to prevent just two lines being taken over a page (and then I'll look up exactly how `\widowpenalties` (with an s) is supposed to work:-)

Comment: If you want to keep more lines together you could try `\widowpenalties=3 10000 10000 150`. But I wouldn't put such restrictions on the pagebreaking: It will probably bite back somewhere else.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer possibly make that an answer, we probably don't have many examples of \widowpenalties on site?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `\widowpenalties` to avoid that two lines are alone on the second page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\textheight=10\baselineskip
\widowpenalties=3 10000 10000 150
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Assuming you want the widow penalty to apply only to the lines you've specified you want `\widowpenalties=4 10000 10000 150 0` here: the last value is repeated. (Try for example `\showthe\widowpenalties4` in your example to see this.)

Comment: It might also be worth noting that the penalties read backward here (first value applies between the last two lines of the paragraph, _etc._)