# What are exactly those \widowpenalties and what are they doing precisely?

Tags: formatting, widows-orphans, penalty

[In this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207621), the author is using the command `\widowpenalties=3 10000 10000 150`.

While I can understand what `\widowpenalty` is doing, I found no documentation for `\widowpenalties3` nor for `\widowpenalties4`. I looked in the TeXBook, in the Companion book, in source2e.pdf, but they don't explain anywhere what those commands are doing, and **how they work exactly**, with precise details.

Could you please shed some light on this notion?

Comment: It's a penalty to avoid having widow lines.

Comment: @Bernard : yes, I definitely can guess this, but have no idea how they precisely work.

Comment: There are some explanations in TeX by Topic, p.238. Maybe it will help?

Comment: OK, it seems to be a duplicate. Then the search function of this website does not work properly. I typed "widowpenalties" with quotes, and found only 1 result, which is not even the relevant question linked here!

Comment: It  can be found on CTAN, or you can install it with your distribution package manager.

Comment: @Watson Search not working properly is a common problem on stack exchange sites in general.  I usually have better luck with google, sometimes prepending "site:https://tex.stackexchange.com" (with the https on the url).  Although in this case, I'm getting 61 results for that search on this site, and the 7th is the one we want.  (And the first is now this question.)

Comment: This is 1599 in e-TeX documentation here: https://v1.overleaf.com/latex/examples/typeset-the-source-code-documentation-for-tex-e-tex-or-pdftex/qkgfgyspnhcv.pdf, but no detail is given!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`widowpenalties` is an e-tex extension so not mentioned in the texbook. Classic tex has `\widowpenalty` which is a penalty for breaking a page at the last line of a paragraph

e-tex has a simple extension to a list

```
\widowpenalties 3 1001  1002 1003
```

would declare a list of 3 penalties with 1001 being used on the last line, 1002 on the last but one and 1003 being used ones before that. as for `\parshape` the last value is repeated)

You can similarly use the list `\clubpenalties` to control page breaking in the initial lines of a paragraph not just after the first line.

This list all the penalty valued parameters available in classic tex and its extensions.

[What are penalties and which ones are defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51263/what-are-penalties-and-which-ones-are-defined/51264#51264)

---

so taking this example

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\showoutput
\showboxdepth3

\clubpenalties 3 1001 1002 0
\widowpenalties 3 2001 2002 0
\interlinepenalty=5


some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text
```

the log shows the  lines as follows

`...\hbox(6.15079+0.0)x345.0, glue set 0.55896 []`  line 1
`...\penalty 1006`                                  interline + first club
`...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.84921`                 
`...\hbox(6.15079+0.0)x345.0, glue set 0.08807 []`  line 2
`...\penalty 1007`                                  interline + 2nd club
`...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.84921`                 
`...\hbox(6.15079+0.0)x345.0, glue set 0.26903 []`  line 3
`...\penalty 5`                                     interline
`...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.84921`                 
`...\hbox(6.15079+0.0)x345.0, glue set 0.08807 []`  line 4
`...\penalty 5`                                     interline
`...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.84921`                 
`...\hbox(6.15079+0.0)x345.0, glue set 0.26903 []`
`...\penalty 5`                                     interline
`...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.84921`                 
`...\hbox(6.15079+0.0)x345.0, glue set 0.08807 []`
`...\penalty 5`                                     interline
`...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.84921`                 
`...\hbox(6.15079+0.0)x345.0, glue set 0.26903 []`
`...\penalty 5`                                     interline
`...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.84921`                 
`...\hbox(6.15079+0.0)x345.0, glue set 0.08807 []`
`...\penalty 5`                                     interline
`...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.84921`                 
`...\hbox(6.15079+0.0)x345.0, glue set 0.26903 []`
`...\penalty 5`                                     interline
`...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.84921`                 
`...\hbox(6.15079+0.0)x345.0, glue set 0.08807 []`
`...\penalty 5`                                     interline
`...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.84921`                 
`...\hbox(6.15079+0.0)x345.0, glue set 0.26903 []`
`...\penalty 5`                                     interline
`...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.84921`                 
`...\hbox(6.15079+0.0)x345.0, glue set 0.08807 []`
`...\penalty 5`                                     interline
`...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.84921`                 
`...\hbox(6.15079+0.0)x345.0, glue set 0.26903 []`
`...\penalty 5`                                     interline
`...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.84921`                 
`...\hbox(6.15079+0.0)x345.0, glue set 0.08807 []`
`...\penalty 2007`                                  interline  + 2nd widow
`...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.84921`                 
`...\hbox(6.15079+0.0)x345.0, glue set 0.26903 []`
`...\penalty 2006`                                  interline  + 1st widow
`...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.84921`                 
`...\hbox(6.15079+0.0)x345.0, glue set 256.5554fil []`  last line of text