# Penalty between paragraphs

Tags: page-breaking, paragraphs

How do I modify the penalty given to a pagebreak between paragraphs? I looked everywhere and could not figure out. If I really need to I can redefine `\par` but I'm unsatisfied with such a hack.

Comment: Related: [What are penalties and which ones are defined?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51263/5764)

Comment: @Werner: Yes I read that many times already, thanks.

Comment: @user21820 So you culd start editing your question for add a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: @Aradnix: I don't have a particular situation with a specific layout problem. Rather, I would like to modify the penalty I asked about. It seems there is no direct way unlike say `\interlinepenalty`.

Comment: There is no (vertical) penalty inserted after a paragraph.

Comment: @egreg: So how do I automatically insert a vertical penalty after a paragraph?

Comment: By redefining `\par`. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg: Lol alright so that's the only way? Is there anything I need to beware of while doing so?

Comment: Are you using Plain TeX or LaTeX? And what's the reason for such a strange request?

Comment: @egreg: Because I was trying to design an environment but neither list items nor paragraphs allow me proper control over the page-breaking behaviour. If you really want to know, I want an environment that can be nested and produces an outline-style list that discourages page-break within inner lists more than outer lists, and also prevents page-break between an inner list and its heading.

Comment: @egreg: I don't mind either, but I would prefer if it is simple like redefining `\par`. I hesitate to redefine `\par` just like that as I don't know what might break.

Comment: iiuc, if you plan to use the code within an environment, your redefinition of `\par` will be kept local to the group, so you shouldn't worry to break things elsewhere.

Comment: @erreka: Thanks for telling me, though actually I want to redefine `\par` because I want to encourage page-break between paragraphs rather than in the middle, if the paragraph is not too long.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The penalty for breaking before the `\parskip` glue inserted between paragraphs is 0, so one possibility is to redefine `\par` to add a `\penalty` node before that skip. One problem doing that in latex is that latex redefines `\par` all the time (after headings and  list items, to control breaking and indentation, in parboxes and minipages (to restore the default definition) etc, so you need to coordinate your redefinition with any other macros that are resetting `\par`.

An alternative way to view the same requirement is that you want to make it more likely that page break happens between paragraphs than mid-paragraph. Given that the inter-paragraph penalty is essentially fixed at 0, rather than change that you can increase the `\interlinepenalty` to discourage breaking between lines.  `\interlinepenalty` is normally 0 (except after section headings, or in the scope of `samepage`) So you can increase it to make breaks between paragraphs more likely.

You also need to add some stretchable glue to the page, either by using `\raggedbottom` or making `\parskip` or some other glue flexible.  If there is no stretchable glue then TeX has no choice in the page breaking, it has to break after the last line that fits on the page, or if the penalty is 10000 so that is not possible it will make an over-full box and over-print the page boundary.

Comment: The problem I had with changing only `\interlinepenalty` (which I already did) is that it is only one of the many penalties, and I had wanted to be able to encourage page-breaking between paragraphs relative to all other places. In the end I did redefine `\par` and so far had no issues.