# \hrulefill not working as expected in \newcommand

Tags: rules

I'm trying to make a simple new command for that creates a break in the text for a "Question and Answer" block preceded and succeeded by a horizontal line.

With the existing code (listed below) the bottom horizontal line does not show.

```
\newcommand{\QandA}[2]{
    \hrulefill \\
    \textbf{Q:  }{#1} \\
    \textbf{A:  }{#2} \\
    \hrulefill}
```

Comment: `\bf` is deprecated: Use `\textbf{...}` or `\bfseries` instead (with proper grouping)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!  I'm new to LaTeX.  I went ahead and made an edit so as not to distract from the central question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No sledgehammer like `tabularx`; the important thing is to avoid `\hrulefill` at the start of a line, because glue disappears at line breaks. The first is after the indentation box or at the beginning of the paragraph like in my answer, but it doesn't disappear there. For the second one we need something that will not vanish at a line break. like `\mbox{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\QandA}[2]{%
  \par\noindent\hrulefill\\*
  \textbf{Q: }#1\\*
  \textbf{A: }#2\\*[-1.25ex]
  \mbox{}\hrulefill\par
}

\begin{document}

Some text before.

\QandA{One}{Two}

Some text after.

\end{document}
```

The use of `*` is in order to avoid page breaks.

[image]

Comment: When you say "no sledgehammer", you just mean that using the tabularx package is overkill for this case, correct?  Also, how did you know that -1.25ex would provide symmetrical spacing?

Comment: @C.Gonzalez Yes, `tabularx` is definitely too much for this application. The value `1.25ex` comes from an educated guess (I tried 1.2 and 1.3, then decided for 1.25).

Comment: Thanks! One other thing - what is meant by "glue"?  I've seen it mentioned in other answers (also the term "penalties" appearing in conjunction).  Let me know if this should be it's own question.

Comment: @C.Gonzalez “Glue” is the term Knuth uses for describing horizontal and vertical spacing that, in TeX, can be flexible (and disappear at appropriate spots, such as page and line breaks). For penalties, see [What are penalties and which ones are defined?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51263/).

Answer (score 4):

You need a "marker" at the beginning of the line in order for the *leader* `\hrulefill` to extend from. Try using `\mbox{}\hrulefill` for the ending rule. However, ...

The following will provide an unbreakable box (in the form of a `tabular`) that will insert your Q&A:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand{\QandA}[2]{%
  \par\noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lX@{}}
    \hline
    \textbf{Q:}& #1 \\
    \textbf{A:}& #2 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \par}

\begin{document}

Some text before.

\QandA{One}{Two}

Some text after.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This produces the desired result; however, I do have a couple of questions.  First, would you mind explaining why my code wouldn't produce that second line?  Second, and somewhat unrelated, why end lines with a comment character but no comment?  Like at the end of your "\newcommand" line.  I've seen that frequently around here.

Comment: Using the sledgehammer…

Comment: @C.Gonzalez: I've mentioned something about your first inquiry in my post. For the second question, see [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](http://goo.gl/awJkj)