# How can I make \cite print the URL of @ONLINE?

Tags: biblatex

I use a custom environment `{readon}` to give some additional article and websites for the read at the end of sections. How can I change `\cite` so that it prints also the URL for `@ONLINE` entries in this list?

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
   @Online{penalties,
     author  = {David Carlisle},
     title   = {What are penalties and which ones are defined?},
     date    = {2012-04-09},
     url     = {https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51264/4918},
     urldate = {2017-06-28},
   }
   @Book{texbytopic,
     author  = {Eijkhout, Victor},
     title   = {\TeX{} by Topic},
     address = {Berlin},
     year    = {2014},
   }
\end{filecontents}

\newenvironment{readon}{%
   \par\bigskip\noindent
   \footnotesize
   \textbf{Further reading \dots}
   \begin{itemize}
}{
   \end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{readon}
   \item \cite[155\psqq]{texbytopic}
   \item \cite{penalties} [[add URL here]]
\end{readon}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Only in `readon`? Or also in other instances when you use `\cite`?

Comment: I’d say only in `readon` but math the moment there are no occurrences of `\cite` outside of the environment. However in that case I could just add the redefinition of `cite` in the definition of `{readon}` to keep it local …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the cite macro to print the URL for `@online` entries

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifnameundef{labelname}
       {}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:title}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}%
  \usebibmacro{cite:url}}

\newbibmacro{cite:url}{%
  \ifentrytype{online}
    {\setunit{\addspace}%
     \printfield{url}}
    {}}
```

Since this modifies the `cite` bibmacro, the solution is specific to the `authoryear` style, but the general idea can be applied for all styles.

Comment: Thanks! It works fine although I had to change to `\ptintfield[siteurl]{url}` to make it use my `\DeclareFieldFormat{citeurl}{[\url{#1}}` setting.

Answer (score 3):

With

```
\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat{citeurl}{\ifentrytype{online}{[\url{#1}]}{}}
```

and then

```
\begin{readon}
    \item \cite[155\psqq]{texbytopic} \citeurl{texbytopic}
    \item \cite{penalties} \citeurl{penalties}
\end{readon}
```

[image]

Comment: Hm … that would require to add an extra macro for every entry. Of course I could wrap this an a new macro and `\let` this to be `\cite`. But what would be the way to change `\cite` itself?

Comment: sure, a simple `\myCite{#1}` should work

Comment: Except for the optional arguments ;-) but I prefer the solution by moewe anyway …

Comment: _With_ an optional argument!

Comment: Sure it is possible (ans not that complicated) but one has to take care of _two_ optional arguments of `\cite`. I just wanted to mention it for sake of completeness if another user comes here later :-)

Comment: It is not important if you need one or two  optional arguments.

Comment: Sorry … how do you mean that?