# Request paragraph in multicol environment to be printed on next page / avoid breaking paragraphs

Tags: page-breaking, paragraphs, multicol

I played a lot with the differed [available penalties](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51263/what-are-penalties-and-which-ones-are-defined). But I cannot achieve what I want. Here an example for explaining:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-4]
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        %\raggedcolumns
        \lipsum[4]
        \textbf{\lipsum[5]}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to prevent that the last paragraph stretches over two pages. So the bold printed part should go on the next page. The rest of the 2-column text should stay on page 1. It may use `\raggedcolumns`, that would be okay with me. A `\newpage` after `\lipsum[4]` would do the trick, but how can I make LaTeX insert it for me?

**EDIT: I need to clarify: The content of the 2-column text is coming from an external source. I do not want to edit it manually: No page break, no environment, nor any other change I need to do to change the 2-column text. Just `\lipsum[4-5]`.**

Comment: I'm not sure I got the question. It is acceptable to insert manually a break command?

Comment: No, I do not want to insert it manually. I want LaTex insert it for me.

Comment: You can make the paragraph unbreakable with a \parbox or minipage.

Comment: I wonder what kind of special (commercial?) application you are trying to build up here given your last question and this one. Your requrements as far as they are visible from those questions are kind of special and not really fitting what multicol is trying to achieve as a standard use cases. That doesn't mean that they can't be acomplished but perhaps you need to consider contracting the development of a special version fitting your requirements.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Yes, indeed it seems that I need another/individual solution. I was hoping to re-resurrect a private, 20-year-old song book without too much effort. Each song is a paragraph that is why I want prevent breaks within. But it seems the best way is to use a current package (e.g. songs.sourceforge.net). That of course requires a lot of re-structuring...

Comment: @JackMiller shouldn't you be able to fairly easily then replace the empty line in your source by something else? E.g.  \par -> \par\filbreak\par  should make your songs come out on the top of columns if they don't fit (except for the last page with balancing and that you can prevent by using multicols*

Answer (score 2):

using the `samepage` environment should have the desired effect:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-4]
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        %\raggedcolumns
        \lipsum[4]
        \begin{samepage}
         \textbf{\lipsum[5]}
        \end{samepage}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Comment: This would be very similar to inserting a `\newpage` which I want to avoid. I clarified my question above.

Comment: I'm not sure that is going to work if that part ever gets across several columns (or ends up being balanced)

Comment: @FrankMittelbach -- you're correct.  it's just as specific as `\newpage`, but it can be useful in its place.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \clubpenalties 15 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 0
        \raggedcolumns
        \lipsum[4]
        \textbf{\lipsum[4]}
        \lipsum[4-88]
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

The line starting with `\clubpenalties 15` adds infinite (10000) penalties for break (either column or page break) for the first 14 rows. Which means that the first 15 lines in a paragraph are always kept together. For longer paragraphs (e.g. see last paragraph on page 5 of sample code) one would need to increase the number of lines which are kept together (by increasing 15 and adding the same number of times `10000` before the last `0`).

`\raggedcolumns` is need to prevent LaTeX from inserting spaces would cause messy looking gaps.