# Better spacing for justified text by increasing hyphenation

Tags: spacing, typography, justification

**Is there a way to make LaTeX hyphenate much more to make spacing in justified text more even?** I am trying to achieve the justification used in Renaissance-era typography (Bram de Does and other typographers following tradition also do this), which seems to often use a large amount of hyphenation to achieve better spacing.

In addition to all this, InDesign (which uses the TeX line-breaking algorithm) has a slider that goes from ‘better spacing’ to ‘fewer hyphenations’. Is there a way to get something like this in LaTeX?

**I tried decreasing the `\hyphenpenalty` to 0, but this did not have the desired effect.** I am wondering if it is possible to increase the penalty for bad spacing in addition to this …

## Update

A [new question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/454304/165273) that asks the same base question, but gets at the core better. I realised that I didn’t express myself very well in this question, so I have created a new one. It also takes into account what I learned from the answer, namely that hyphenation cannot save bad justification.

Comment: Making hyphenation more desirable can actually *increase* the number of lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make `\hypenpenalty` negative, if you wish to go this way.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[main=latin]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[width=15cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}

\begin{document}


\begin{multicols*}{2}
  \lipsum[1]

  \columnbreak

  {\hyphenpenalty=-200 \lipsum[1] }
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

(I have loaded `babel` with the `latin` option as the `lipsum` text is in Latin.)  Note that as egreg points out, encouraging more hyphenation does not necessarily improve the spacing.

There are a number of other approaches to get better spacing in narrow columns.  One is using the `microtype` package, that makes subtle minor adjustments to spacing to get better line breaks.  See [What are penalties and which ones are defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51263/15925) for a discussion of various parameters that can be tweaked.  Here is the effect of the microtype package:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[main=latin]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[width=15cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{microtype}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}

\begin{document}


\begin{multicols*}{2}
  \microtypesetup{activate=false}
  \lipsum[1]

  \columnbreak

  {\microtypesetup{activate=true} \lipsum[1] }
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Lipsum text is not really a good specimen, because it's in pseudo Latin. You may try with `kantlipsum` or other packages that provide English text.

Comment: @egreg Of course.  I have now updated so latin hyphenation patterns are used.

Comment: And now it shows better the issue: with more frequent hyphenation the spaces *increase*.