How to force a line never to appear at the top of the page
I have a line of text that should not be separated from what came before it by a page break.  (If it matters, what came before it is a text environment).  I.E. How do I force a line of text to never be the first line in a page?
Here is my minimal example:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{quotation}
Very long quote about honour and fate, having to do with family and children, torture and death, with rending of garments and gnashing of teeth thrown in for good measure.
\end{quotation}
\raggedleft{---Last speech to the Doomed Squadron, 57 Years Before The Fall}

\end{document}

In my example, I want the text inside of \raggedleft to remain attached to the quotation environment.
UPDATE1:  I cannot use vbox because I could have a very long multi-paragrah quotation that should break across pages.
UPDATE2: I intend to implement an environment with these characteristics, so the solution must be able to be implemented regardless of context.  I.E. needspace will not work because I would have to know if/when I need space.

Ses if this helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51263/what-are-penalties-and-which-ones-are-defined

Can you not put that paragraph in a box or something so that it does not break?

It would help if you gave us an example to work with.  Is this all one paragraph, and you need the last line to not be on the next page?  Or is the widow line a new paragraph, but it should still be attached to the previous paragraph?  Or is the previous thing not quite a paragraph, but some other text environment?

\@afterheading also does that.

TeX works with box-penalty-glue principle. If you insert \penalty10000 just before a glue then the glue is unbreakable. The macro \nobreak is a shortcut for \penalty10000.
Insert the following just before \end{quotation}:
\par\nobreak \countdef\penalty=0

\par returns to vertical mode, \nobreak inserts the penalty 10000 and \countdef\penalty=0 is \penalty obfuscation, because the LaTeX environment inserts another penalty at the end of this environment but we don't want such second penalty here. The setting is local, so the original meaning of the \penalty primitive is restored at the end of the group which is opened by the LaTeX environment quotation.

Doesn't the initial \par in your answer insert an extra vertical space that I would not want added?

No, \par doesn't insert any vertical space.

I am not very good at TeX internals.  I can use the code without understanding it, but I would like to understand it.  With \newcount\nopenalty I get a new dummy variable with a default value of 0?  After \nobreak, the penalty inside the quotation is 10000.  Then I store this 10,000 penalty into \nopenalty.  But the real true penalty that LaTeX will understand is still 10,000.  Then I leave the quotation, after which the true real penalty will reset back to normal.  Then the raggedleft line is typeset with normal penalty.  How does the \nopenalty variable help at all?

The \penalty primitive has a syntax \penalty number. When it is used then the given penalty is inserted. The \nobreak macro does it. Then the control sequence \penalty gets another meaning than its original primitive. Now it is a register \nopenalty. The register assignment has a syntax register number, i.e. \penalty number acts like assignment and doesn't insert anything to the typesetting output. The \penalty something is somewhere in the LaTeX macros for closing quotation environment. and it does nothing in typesetting output now.  That was the puropse.

You can use the package needspace and add a \Needspace{} close to the end of the quote to force some of the text to be printed on the following page before the right-aligned text.
The last sentence in the quote -- "And one more sentence." -- appears on the first page when \Needspace{5cm} is commented out, and when it is included, the sentence is moved to the following page.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum, needspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{quotation}
Very long quote about honour and fate, having to do with family and children, torture and death, with rending of garments and gnashing of teeth thrown in for good measure.

\lipsum[1-4]

\Needspace{5cm}
And one more sentence.
\end{quotation}
\raggedleft{---Last speech to the Doomed Squadron, 57 Years Before The Fall}

\end{document}



Thank you for your response.  I am imagining a very long multi-paragraph quotation, and I would like my environment to be able to break across page breaks, like the quotation environment itself does.  That is why \vbox is not an option for me.

Ah, sorrry. See modified answer above.

I am sorry to be such a downer...  Your answer is perfect for a single-use on-the-spot situation.  I like it.  However, I want to create an environment where I do not know whether I will need the extra space or not.  So I was looking for a more general solution that I could use in an environment definition.
