# Prevent LaTeX from making pages longer or shorter (i.e. changing the text height)

Tags: page-breaking, widows-orphans

When I try to prevent widows/orphans by increasing `\widowpenalty`and `clubpenalty`, `LaTeX` usually decides to either make the page one line shorter (to prevent an orphan) or one line longer (to prevent a widow on the next page).
How do I make `LaTeX` attempt to minimize widows/orphans, but without using this method? I have a vertical rubber length skip every few paragraphs and I was hoping `LaTeX` would use that instead.

Follow-up question: Making the page one line shorter or longer is permissible in a book if the facing page is shortened/lengthened by the same number of lines. 
Is there a way to let `LaTeX` make a page one line shorter or longer as long as the two facing page of a spread are always the same length?

Here's my MWE. Notice that on same pages there's a widow/orphan *and* the facing page has a different length. For example, on pages 8-9 we get two pages of unequal length for no apparent reason!

```
\documentclass[11pt, icelandic, leqno]{book}
\usepackage[textwidth=112mm,textheight=190mm, paperwidth=153mm, paperheight=230mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % if using utf8
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\frenchspacing

% To avoid headers and footers
% choose one of the below:

%\usepackage[defaultlines=2, all]{nowidow}

%\widowpenalty10000
%\clubpenalty10000

\widowpenalty300
\clubpenalty300

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\filright\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}
  {\icelandicordinal{chapter}~\MakeLowercase\chaptertitlename}
  {20pt}
  {\huge}
\usepackage{titleps}
\newpagestyle{myfancy}{
    \sethead[\textsc{\chaptertitle}][][]
    {}{}{\textsc{\thesection{} \sectiontitle{}}}
    \setfoot[\usepage][][]
    {}{}{\usepage}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{myfancy}

\chapter*{Intro}
\sethead[\textsc{Intro}][][]
{}{}{\textsc{Intro}}

%\lipsum[4-57]
\lipsum[4-8]
\medskip
\lipsum[9-15]
\medskip
\lipsum[16-23]
\medskip
\lipsum[24-35]
\medskip
\lipsum[36-40]
\medskip
\lipsum[41-52]
\medskip
\lipsum[53-57]

\end{document}
```

Comment: see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248417/what-are-the-downsides-of-widowpenalty10000-clubpenalty10000/248419#248419

Comment: I just found out that the `textheight` and `baselineskip` were incompatible (textheight was not equal to a whole number og baselineskips + topskip). Adding the `heightrounded` option to `geometry` fixed this. An answer to the follow-up question (if an answer exists) is still appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the reason LaTeX didn't have consistent textheight (one `\baselineskip` less on one page, one `\baselineskip` more on another) was that the `\textheight` and `\baselineskip` set by

```
\usepackage[textwidth=112mm,textheight=190mm, paperwidth=153mm, paperheight=230mm]{geometry}
```

were incompatible. It is my understanding that if `\textheight` is not equal to n times `\baselineskip` plus `\topskip` for some integer n, then an underfull vbox is unavoidable in some cases, prompting LaTeX to break pages in weird places.

Thankfully, there's an easy fix. Just use the option `heightrounded`:

```
\usepackage[textwidth=112mm,textheight=190mm, paperwidth=153mm, paperheight=230mm heightrounded]{geometry}
```

It will round `\textheight` to a better value. You can also set it manually.

With this setting and moderate values of `\widowpenalty` and `\clubpenalty` (I'm using 500), you shouldn't run into this problem. If you want to prevent a widow or orphan by increasing/decreasing the text height on both pages of a spread, you can add `\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}` (or `-\baselineskip`) on both sides of the page break. I'm not aware of a better solution yet.