# Do not start paragraph on last line of page

Tags: paragraphs

Similar to how sections try to avoid starting on the last line of a page, how can I apply similar behavior to paragraphs?

In other words, do not start a paragraph on a page unless there is room for at least two lines of that paragraph on that page.

Comment: Check for widow and orphan (club?) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/how-do-i-prevent-widow-orphan-lines

Comment: Are you talking about a `\paragraph{...}` or about some text followed by an empty line or `\par`?

Comment: @samcarter I am referring to a standard paragraph creates by text following an empty line or \par, not \paragraph.

Comment: @PaintingInAir Thanks for the clarification!  In this case I suggest the `nowidow` package. `\usepackage[defaultlines=2,all]{nowidow}`

Comment: @Fran Thank you, it looks like this is the same problem. I did not find that question because I did not know that these are called orphans or clubs.