# Should you \newpage when a section has the chance to fill an entire page?

Tags: page-breaking, layout

Concretely in the case that I attached here (it's a real case),
the chapter ends on page 39. Page 38 starts a new subsection that overflows into page 39 but would have also fit into page 39 as a whole.

The question is: Should I prepend a `\newpage`? Or should I trust in the wisdom of LaTeX's auto-formatting?

[image: Screenshot of PDF. Content hidden by gray boxes.]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usualy you should trust in the wisdom of LaTeX, because if this is not the "real final final version" something could change and then a `\newpage` at the wrong location would look terrible. If it is only a subsubsection and there are multiple lines and not just one it should be ok. For oneliners there are penalties, see [How do I prevent widow/orphan lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4152/123129).

Answer (score 1):

Go with LaTeX until your final printing when you can do some last minute tweaks to the document layout.

Think what happens if you keep using `\newpage` but then add or subtract text from earlier in the document. Are your `\newpage`s then in their best place?